# Laravel - htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

My blade.php code is:

```
{!! Form::input('text', 'tactic[]', null, array('id' => 'tactic', 'class' => ' form-control TabOnEnter', 'placeholder' => 'Tactics_1')) !!}
```

HtmlBuilder.php code is

```
public function escapeAll($value)
{
    return htmlentities($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}
```

The error message is:

```
ErrorException in HtmlBuilder.php line 65:
htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: /home/seyali-02/dev/htdocs/scam/resources/views/dashboard/Scam/edit.blade.php)
```

And i have changed the blade.php as like

```
{!! Form::input('text','', 'tactic[]', null, array('id' => 'tactic', 'class' => ' form-control TabOnEnter', 'placeholder' => 'Tactics_1')) !!}
```

and

```
{!! Form::text('name', 'tactic[]', null, array('id' => 'tactic', 'class' => ' form-control TabOnEnter', 'placeholder' => 'Tactics_1')) !!}
```

and also `text('text',` .. But nothing works for me and throwing me the same error as i mentioned above.. I have gone through all the similar questions related to this but none of those answers solved my problem . So please avoid doing duplication of this question and give me clear and correct solution..

Comment: what the value of $value variable? as i see this is an array. can you show us var_dump($value)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding `tactic[]` to the name which is an array and hence when you post the data it is going as an array. Either remove it or at php end use `implode`.

Comment: Can you let me know how to make use of implode , because i am very beginner of php and laravel??

Comment: @ManiRaj Follow the link mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks, will check and let you know if i face any issues regarding it..

Comment: Here is a brief description @ManiRaj, Implode can take 2 parameters first is the Delimiter and Second parameter is the Array, and implode will simply join the elements of array to form one string. Eg. `$array = ['a','b','c']; echo implode('-', $array);` output will be `a-b-c-d`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take the input as an array then you can use this code

{!! Form::text('tactic[]',null,['id' => 'tactic', 'class' => ' form-control TabOnEnter', 'placeholder' => 'Tactics_1']) !!}